# Can't determine if my asp.net session implementation is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am very confused in my implementation of sessions in asp.net web application. My logic is once user enters user name+password, I validate credentials and then create a new session with some user info[All I am after from this point onward is that this user has access to restricted resources and a user must never be able to access those resources unless he/she is authenticated]. This I validate on each request and the rest. Here is my issue though. I have many places in the website where I have html links, and I read that if I have a link such as

```
<a href='resource1.aspx'>resource 1</a>
```

This will generate a new session id, hence in reality invalidating the existing session id, which in my case will be treated as session expired and user is sent to login page. While reading up on this issue I came across an asp.net API method[

```
Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(url);
```

] which prepends the session id to each request hence resolving the new session id generation for each link. Though it resolves session breaking issue it does add the session id next to all of the urls and now session id can be seen in the source code( view source for web page). I really don't want to use cookies and want to use session for user sessions...Can some one please help me create a system which will work the way I wish it to ? if I am doing it utterly incorrect, I would really really appreciate a details discussion and if possible some example...Thanks you much in advance..

Comment: What makes you think that an <a> tag will generate a new session id?

Comment: Why are you implementing sessions at all?  There's already a `Session` class that's built for exactly that purpose (and isn't invalidated by clicking on a link since it's cookie-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use [cookieless sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which add a session id to all links in order to be able to track the sessions.

The other (much more common, standard and IMO secure) approach is to use normal sessions, which auto creates a session cookie (when you use the `.Session` object), and uses that to determin the current session. If you don't want a cookie you'll have to stick with cookieless, and the session id in the url.